# python queue using embedded list

Tags: python, queue

Write a class and implement a list using embedded python list.

Input like : 4 9 3 5

Output should be like: 3 4 5 9

I use this code for taking the input values and split it to the list

```
s = input()
numbers = map(int, s.split())
```

How can i build up a class for this listPQ that takes the lists values and put, get and check if the list is empty?

To try if your queue works:

```
   q = ListPQ()
   q.put(3)
   q.put(4)
   x = q.get()
   y = q.get()
   print(x,y)   #it should print 3 4
```

Comment: I don't get how you put 1 and 2 but then get 3 and 4 ?

Comment: can you define (e.g. via a link) what do you mean by `embedded list` exactly, please? [double ended queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) by any chance?

Comment: What they mean with embedded list functions is linked to: http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: native python lists? never heard about them as being "embedded" previously, huh. in that case, adarsh answer looks good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [heapq](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/heapq.html) module from the python standard library. Then it is even possible without a class.

Without class:

```
import heapq
h = []
heapq.heappush(h, 4)
heapq.heappush(h, 3)
heapq.heappush(h, 9)
heapq.heappush(h, 5)
print(heapq.heappop(h))
print(heapq.heappop(h))
print(heapq.heappop(h))
print(heapq.heappop(h))
```

the output would be (space instead of newline):

```
3 4 9 5
```

If you need a class you can do it as follows:

```
class ListPQ():
    def __init__(self):
        self.h = []

    def put(self, item):
        heapq.heappush(self.h, item)

    def get(self):
        return heapq.heappop(self.h)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class ListPQ():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pq = []

    def put(self, val):
        # Write code to put the number and keep it in sorted way, however you decide to
        # you can use self.pq to access the list and add stuff to it... this instance
        # of the class will have it saved.
        self.pq.append(val)
        self.pq.sort() # This is just for brevity, you can use your own algo for this

    def get(self):
        # likewise, use the self.pq to pop it out like,
        return self.pq.pop(-1)

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self.pq) == 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<ListPQ: %r>" % self.pq
```

Now you can go ahead and use `print(instance_of_listpq)` and this will print out the list as it's written in the `__repr__` method.

Hope this helps now!

Comment: How can i use def put function to put the values in a abstract data queue? I use the input value and then split the list. And how can i try if the queue works on that list?

Comment: I'll modify it to show you there... you can pass the value you want to be entered there and also you can use __repr__ method be able to use the print on an instance of this class